# How to format string width with a runtime calculated variable?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I set `40` to be a variable let say `temp` which calculate on the fly and passed instead of `40` in this format string:

`{:<40}.format('aa')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
>>> width = 40
>>> '{0:<{width}}'.format('aa', width=width)
'aa                                      '
```